# I have a question relating to the Ethereum transaction

Tags: go-ethereum

The amount of I had was transferred to another wallet I didn't know.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xcf487d1a303b42bb419f06717209ef5358294759

I have a few questions about why this could happen.

1. Can I still send Ethereum to another wallet even if my account is locked?
2. Do any "geth" console commands allow you to view your account and password information?
3. Is there a way to find it even if I lose my Ethereum wallet password?
4. What should I do to prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 0):

1. No. If the account is locked, it's impossible to send Ethereum to another wallet. However, is somebody get your keystore he can indipendently try to unlock it with a password bruteforce, so choose a safe passphrase (my recommandation is > 14 characters)
2. No command can show you the password information, as it's not stored anywhere but it's used only to decrypt the keystore
3. If you lost your Ethereum keystore passphrase, there's no way you could recover your private key, but bruteforce the wallet
4. NEVER expose the "personal" api on you geth node, choose a safe passphrase, keep the keystore safe, never unlock your account if your eth / web3 rpc api are exposed